# Kubernetes Cluster Entrypoint On-Prem

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, high-availability

I want to set up a Kubernetes cluster on-Prem directly on VMs. Since we are not talking about using a cloud provider exposing my service as type LoadBalancer may not directly make sense. I understand MetalLB could be an option but I don’t have a pool of IP addresses to assign it.

I want an entry point into my cluster to which I can point my DNS A record to. I have a couple of solutions in mind but not sure if one is better than the other or there are other better solutions.

1. Exposing my service on NodePort and using an external load balancer. I can make the external LB my entry point.
2. Running an Ingress Controller on NodePort which routes traffic to my ClusterIP services internally. I could load balance between the Ingress NodePorts using an external LB and make it my entry point.

I only want to expose one service from my cluster to the outside world. In that case I am not sure how using Ingress will add any advantage.

Please help me out my sharing your thoughts and suggestions!

Comment: A pool can be as big as `/32`.

Comment: I understand that. What if it is a shared network and you don’t have complete control over it? If I use MetalLB still I have to use a public facing VM to point the DNS and forward incoming requests right?

Comment: The setup heavily depends on your requirements and network setup. Are we talking about a service you only want to provide internally (within your corporate network, for example) or do you want to expose it to the public internet? How is DNS provisioning done? The advantage that ingress gives you is that you can have multiple services available under the same IP -- think name based virtual hosting. MetalLB gives you the advantage that in a multi-node cluster, the external IP(s) are bound to the active MetalLB node -- think failover.